# Where do I put my citation of an article for a short story in MLA?

Tags: mla

I'm writing an essay in which I retell the story of an African-American girl who was in poverty, as it is told in a New York Times article.  I want to cite the article properly.

Comment: There are various citation systems around one of which is the *Harvard System* and one the *Oxford System*. You are likely to get a variety of responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the MLA... your question specifies the MLA... so, let's stay there. Make sure your quote is not too long. Generally the citation comes after the first short quote or after the block quote; the citation is in parentheses, e.g.: (Miligan, 23); the full citation is in the bibliography, e.g.: Miligan, George: *My life along the Wabash*, Harper Publishers, 1903).

Comment: Within the last ten years I have been taught, in a British university department to write that as follows: Miligan, George: *My life along the Wabash* (London and San Francisco, 1903). We were told not to state the name of the publisher, but the place of publication.

Comment: @WS2 Yea, that's about right.